# Elastic Search Percolate Boolean Queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get boolean queries which are stored in ES using **Percolate** API.

Index mapping is given below

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my-index' -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "taggers": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

I am inserting records like this (Queries contain proper boolean format (AND, OR, NOT etc) as given in below example)

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my-index/.percolator/1' -d '{
        "query" : {
            "match" : {
                "content" : "Audi AND BMW"
            }
        }
}'
```

And then I am posting a document to get matched queries.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my-index/my-type/_percolate' -d '{
    "doc" : {
        "content" : "I like audi very much"
    }
}'
```

In above case no records should come because boolean query is "Audi **AND** BMW" but it is still giving record. It means that it is ignoring **AND** condition. I am not able to figure out that why it is not working for boolean queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to percolate this query instead, `match` queries do not understand the `AND` operator (they will treat it like the normal token `and`), but `query_string` does.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my-index/.percolator/1' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "Audi AND BMW",
            "default_field": "content"
        }
    }
}'
```